# isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext

Tags: android, flutter, entity-framework, gradle, flutter-layout

How to solve this problem

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie-0.9.10/lib/src/chewie_player.dar
t:276:17: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'Bu
ildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/p
ackages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inh
eritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
        context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_ChewieControllerProvider)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie_audio-1.0.0+1/lib/src/chewie_pla
yer.dart:101:17: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the cl
ass 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/p
ackages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inh
eritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
        context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_ChewieAudioControllerProvider)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to
  get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 56s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     118.6s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using an old version of [chewie](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie). 0.9.10 is supporting an older version of Flutter. In recent versions of Flutter, `inheritFromWidgetOfExactType` is deprecated in favor of `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType`. This issue was fixed in version 0.10.4 of chewie.

Upgrade the version number in your `pubspec.yaml`. For example to the latest version:

```
chewie: ^1.2.2
```